# Font icon is displayed through Iconify only after rotating the device

Tags: android, fonts, font-awesome

I'm testing the [Iconify](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify) library to display font icons into my android app. It works, but the problem is that when I launch the app I can only see the icon's `{...}` block which references the special character (e.g. I see `{fa-android}` instead of seeing the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) android icon).

Only after rotation of device the font icon replaces the character code.

Following the library's documentation this is what I use to load the font in the `onCreate()` method:

```
Iconify.with(new FontAwesomeModule());
```

Comment: Are you putting `Iconify.with(new FontAwesomeModule());` in the onCreate method of the Application class?

Comment: @chRyNaN wow I missed that... I was using it in MainActivity. I corrected it and it works fine. Thanks!